# How can I install wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I don't have a clue about how to install the latest stable version of [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html). When I download and uncompress the tar.xz  I get four folders:

- lib
- bin
- include
- share

What should I do with this files?

Comment: See also: [How can I install the latest wkhtmltopdf on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/959152/10425)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install it without that files, just open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

Then use it from the command line like:

```
wkhtmltopdf example.org
wkhtmltoimage example.org
```

---

Or you can copy the files you've downloaded to /usr folder using your window manager or running `sudo mv * /usr` from in the directory you uncompressed the tar.xz file.

---

Or you can run the file from where you extracted them using:

```
chmod -R u+x /extracted/path
./extracted/path/bin/wkhtmltopdf <arguments>
```

Cheers.

Comment: That's a valid way to install it, although the version of `wkhtmltopdf` in the Ubuntu repositories is already slightly outdated.

Comment: I've improved my answers about it. Just copy the files to /usr directory.

Comment: That requires `sudo` privileges, and there is no need to move them to `/usr` anyway. You can just run the binary from whenever the tarball is extracted.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer according to that information, asker asked about installing the software, though, there's no difference at all, there are a lot of ways of doing it.

Comment: There are indeed many ways, but unless the OP explicitly wants the binary to be available to _all_ users, I would avoid telling him to use `sudo` to `mv` files into `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this before the answer, it works!, Thank you.

Comment: @razorx Well one thing is missing here, if you are installing `wkhtmltopdf` manually then you should also install some dependencies. `apt-get install libxrender1 fontconfig xvfb` . Also Would be nice to move them to to `bin` folder by running `cp wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Answer (score 0):

The `wkhtmltopdf` binary is found in the `bin/` directory ("bin" stands for binaries). Therefore, to run it in the terminal, `cd` to `bin/` and run `./wkhtmltopdf` with appropriate arguments.