# How can I install the latest wkhtmltopdf on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, wkhtmltopdf

Currently (25.09.2017)

```
$ sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

installs `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.4`, but [the website](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) shows that we have version 0.12.4 already.

How can I install the latest version of wkhtmltopdf on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 18):

#### Steps to install `wkhtmltopdf` 0.12.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Log in as `root`, then:

```
cd ~
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
tar vxf wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz 
cp wkhtmltox/bin/wk* /usr/local/bin/
```

And you can confirm with:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf --version
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 (with patched qt)
```

By the way, I chose 0.12.3 instead of 0.12.4 because of a strange page sizing issue, discussed [on the `wkhtmltopdf` GitHub](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3226).

Comment: Did you need to make your extracted file(s) executable?

Comment: @user535733 I didn't have to but I was logged in to the server as `root`.

Comment: That's rather important for people trying your solution to know. Do you have a non-root solution? Suggesting unskilled users jump to a root prompt for such a trivial action seems unwise.

Comment: @user535733 I'm definitely not suggesting jumping to a root prompt, but they can always use `sudo` if it's a system-wide installation requirement. Feel free to make any edits to the answer.

Comment: No intent to criticize the solution, apologies if it seemed so. Merely suggested a minor addition, to prevent "Hey, this didn't work for me" complaints.

Comment: @user535733 No worries. :) Hopefully this comment thread can now act as documentation for people that might need to use `sudo`.

Comment: Had to install `libssl1.0-dev` on Lubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5):

```
$ sudo apt-get install wget
$ mkdir wkhtmltopdf-download
$ cd wkhtmltopdf-download
wkhtmltopdf-download $ wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
wkhtmltopdf-download $ tar xf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
wkhtmltopdf-download $ cd wkhtmltox/bin
```

Then just move the binaries somewhere in your `PATH`. See

```
$ echo $PATH
```

For me, it was `mv * /home/math/bin`. And finally:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf --version
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 (with patched qt)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of this moment, when you try to install wkhtmltopdf from the Ubuntu's repositories, it will install the version 0.12.4.